# Issue with authenticating user using javascript and GMail API

Tags: javascript, email, oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-api

I am learning javascript and API's and I am practicing with Gmail. I authenticate a Gmail using in a javascript web page.

I got it to work but I am trying to console log the user's email after they authenticate. I tried many things with no success

When user clicks the button  `handleAuthClick(event)` to open an iframe and start auth process.

**how can I console.log the email address?**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var CLIENT_ID = '123.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  var SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/'];
  /**
   * Check if current user has authorized this application.
   */
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, handleAuthResult);
  }

function listMessages(userId, query, callback) {
  var getPageOfMessages = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      result = result.concat(resp.messages);
      var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
      if (nextPageToken) {
        request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          'userId': userId,
          'pageToken': nextPageToken,
          'q': query
        });
        getPageOfMessages(request, result);
        console.log("hey its done" + result)
      } else {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  };
  var initialRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    'userId': userId,
    'q': query
  });
  getPageOfMessages(initialRequest, []);
}

  /**
   * Handle response from authorization server.
   *
   * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
   */
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
      //authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadGmailApi();
      console.log(resp.email);

    } else {
      // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
      // clicking authorize button.
      //authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';

      console.log("hey form else")
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
   *
   * @param {Event} event Button click event.
   */
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
    listMessages('me',"is:unread");// this returns big list of objects yee haw
    console.log("hey there from handleAuthClick");

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Load Gmail API client library. List labels once client library
   * is loaded.
   */
  function loadGmailApi() {
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', listLabels);

  }

  /**
   * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
   * are found an appropriate message is printed.
   */
  function listLabels() {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
      'userId': 'me'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var labels = resp.labels;
      appendPre('Labels:');

      if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
          var label = labels[i];
          appendPre(label.name)
          cosnole.log(label.name)
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No Labels found.');
      }
    });
  }

  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('output');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand where you try to console the email address? After the authorize it's go to the call back function 'handleAuthResult' , then you load the gmail API in the function 'loadGmailApi' and after this row :

```
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', listLabels);
```

You could ask what ever you want with gapi.client methodS from [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) and for mail address specific with `gapi.auth2.BasicProfile`